# How can I mock external API during testing in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5

I want to test an HTTP route in laravel. The action function of the URL calls a helper function, which calls an external API. How can I mock the external API call while testing?

```
public function actionFunction(){

     $helper = new HelperClassHelper();

     return Response::json($helper->getNames());

}
```

Here, the getNames() function makes an external API call. How do I mock it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the HelperClassHelper as a dependency in the action, and then you are able to mock it in the test:

```
public function actionFunction(HelperClassHelper $helper){
     return Response::json($helper->getNames());
}
```

In the test:

```
$this->app->bind(HelperClassHelper::class, function () { /* return mock */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you please explain the mocking part too? I am doing it for the first time and it's a bit complex for me.

Comment: @SreekanthMK, when you add `HelperClassHelper` to the method it is resolved from the container (dependency injection). So in the the test you can do `$this->app->bind...` which will replace the real class in the container with a mock.

Comment: I added this in the test, $this->app->bind(InfusionsoftHelper::class, function() { 
            return "this is a mock";
         }); But still there is no change.

Answer (score 1):

let me made this simple.

follow this step :

1.) add service `app/Services/MyService/HttpClient.php`. in this case i'm using postman api.

```
namespace App\Services\MyService;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;

class HttpClient
{
    public function send(array $payload) : Response
    {
        return app(Client::class)
            ->request('POST', 'https://postman-echo.com/post', $payload);
    }
}
```

2.) add controller `app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\MyService\HttpClient;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $response = app(HttpClient::class)->send($request->toArray());
        $data = json_decode( $response->getBody()->getContents(),true);
        return response()->json(
            $data,
            $response->getStatusCode()
        );
    }
}
```

3.) add test file `tests/Feature/SampleTest.php`

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Services\MyService\HttpClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Tests\TestCase;

class SampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        //do awesome thing
    }

    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->mock(HttpClient::class, function ($mock) {
            return $mock->shouldReceive('send')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn(new Response(
                $status = 200,
                $headers = [],
                File::get(base_path('tests/files/success.json'))
            ));
        });
        $data = [
            'mock' => 'no'
        ];
        $response = $this->call('post','/test', $data);
        $response->assertExactJson(['mock' => 'yes']);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

4.) add json file `tests/files/success.json` for fake response :

```
{
    "mock" : "yes"
}
```